# in tikz, use underscore in node name and node text at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I want to use a string `a_b` as the node name and node text, with xelatex implement.

A newcommand to use the same string on node name and node text is defined:

```
\newcommand\block[1][ ]{\node[rectangle,draw](#1){#1}}
```

A problem about underscore is:

- I have to escape underscore in the node text, because I want to print "a_b" in the node
- I can not escape underscore in the node name

So either `\block[a\_b]` or `\block[a_b]` will make error.

Can I use underscore when keep the `\block` command?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Just to clarify, the node text should contain an explicit underscore? I.e. the output should be as `a\_b`, and not a with subscript b? By the way, because you defined that command with an optional argument (the `[  ]` in the command definition indicates that the command has an optional argument), you should use the command as `\block[a]` not `\block{a}`. (That doesn't solve your problem, just mentioning it.)

Comment: you might be able to use `{\detokenize{#1}}` instead of `{#1}`, if that does not work, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and use for testing.

Comment: Maybe `\block[{a_b}]` could do the job.

Comment: @daleif Probably the other way around. You'd want `\node[rectangle,draw] (\detokenize{#1}) {#1}`, otherwise `\block[\textbf{a}]` will look funny.

Comment: @HenriMenke the OP never mentioned anything about adding formatting to `#1`, that of course will not work and shortcuts like this should not be used in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! If you just want to make this work with plain expressions such as `a_b` or the like, that don't contain any additional macros, you could make use of the `xstring` package to replace the underscore in the node text by its equivalent macro, such as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\block[1][ ]{%
    \node[rectangle,draw](#1){\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\textunderscore}};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \block[a_b]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, as daleif pointed out in their comment, just using `\detokenize{#1}` should also do the job:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\newcommand\block[1][ ]{%
    \node[rectangle,draw](#1){\detokenize{#1}};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \block[a_b]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Both should give the same result:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look right. Try `\block[\textbf{a_b}]`

Comment: Well, to be honest, I did not consider such a thing, since the optional argument was considered to be the node name and the node text, and I just thought that having a node name `\textbf{a_b}` was out of the question already. But you are right, this would only work without additional macros added.